# When the room topic changes, can we see a diff?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Messages like this aren't helpful:

[image]

Perhaps they could look something more like this?

[image]

Comment: blame-fredley! Also can we stop the formatting break with italic text and "]"'s!

Comment: @kalina I thought it'd be clear that it's caused by the star in 'arq*'. Also I think this feature request will get shot down because we're not exactly using the feature as one's supposed to. (How is one supposed to use this feature anyway?)

Comment: @badp'skitten Why is this a feature?

Comment: @badp'skitten I didn't see the star, it was parsed by markdown. ;)

Comment: @fredley I think it was built with chat.SO in mind more than chat.SE

Comment: @badp'skitten What's a topic?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is needed as everything a user needs to know this is already in place.

If you're interested in the diff just search for `Room topic changed to:` in the chat history which will get you every single room name change.

The only caveat is that you won't get the original room name, but I don't think that's such a big deal either.

Personally I'm just more interested in getting the current topic than the diff to notice the change.